# IOS NSDate compare bug?

Tags: ios, nsdate, uidatepicker

This is my problem :

i have 2 datepicker and i want to compare them

```
NSDate *dateFrom = [_dateFromPicker date];
NSDate *dateTo = [_dateToPicker date];

if ([dateFrom compare:dateTo] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"day2 > day1");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Ok");
}
```

If I compare 2 same date (for ex 26-02-2015 & 26-02-2015)

the first time it will work but if i change the second date to 27 then again to 26 i get the day2 > day1 ...

Any idea why ?

Comment: `NSLog` the two dates. It's probably because the time changes.

Comment: i did nslog the 2 dates it was showing the exact same date
I finaly made it work by changing the time of the date like this :
NSDate *dateFrom = [calendar dateBySettingHour:0 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:[_dateFromPicker date] options:0];
and it worked fine